# GCP PubSub: Publishing messages takes time when there is a spike in incoming messages to publish

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-java-client

Setup:

1. Springboot & Kotlin app hosted in GCP GKE
2. Above app receives data from AMQP/rabbitMQ service
3. Above app receives AMQP data and publishes into Google cloud PubSub , GCP GKE and PubSub are in different GCP projects , data published using service account
4. PubSub Push subscription - Cloud function . Memory 512MB, FirstGen, Maximum 3000 instances

Problem:
Sometimes when there is a spike in AMQP messages seeing delays in publish around 20-60 seconds. For instance after receiving the message from AMQP , time taken to publish is around 20-60 seconds.

Questions:

1. Is my way of logging correct, does publish time means publishing to push subscription or invoked cloud function completion.
2. What do i need to do to increase the throughput? These messages are time sensitive means they need to be delivered as soon as its created.
3. Is there something i need to consider to scale when there is a spike . like horizontal scaling , multiple publish clients ,etc.,

```
fun publishCode(receivedTime:LocalDateTime){
    PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
            .setData(ByteString.copyFrom(message.body))
            .build()?.let {
                val apiFuture: ApiFuture<String> = publisher.publish(it) //publisher created using bean
                ApiFutures.addCallback(apiFuture, object : ApiFutureCallback<String> {
                    override fun onSuccess(messageID: String?) {
                        val publishedTime = getCurrentTime()
                        log.info("Published success : Received:$receivedTime Published:$publishedTime"
                    }
                })
            } 
}

@Bean
fun publisher(): Publisher {
    return Publisher.newBuilder("$topicToPublish").setRetrySettings(retrySettings)
            .build()
}
```

Comment: (1) Who knows; you're overloaded Log before and after, calc. delta. If the delta's variance is high, you can't trust the "after" time. (2,3): 1. CF is not good for highly variable load. Use Cloud Run. Changes are minimal. 2. Make sure it's not CF where you're chocking. Spinning up additional CFs is expensive, with Java runtime doubly so! 3. You didn't mention the message size. There are [PubSub quotas](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas), calculate if you are within the quotas, have them extended for you if so.